# Updating 1 table from another using wheres

Tags: sql-server

Trying to update one column, from another table with the highest Date.

`Table 1` Example:

```
PartNumber | Cost 
1000       | .10
1001       | .20
```

`Table 2` Example:

```
PartNumber | Cost | Date
1000       | .10  | 2017-01-01
1000       | .50  | 2017-02-01
1001       | .20  | 2017-01-01
1002       | .50  | 2017-02-02
```

I would like to update table 1 with the most recent values from table2, which would be .50 for each... The query I use to update this has worked just fine until I realized I was not grabbing the correct Cost because there were multiples.. I now want to grab the highest dated revision.

My query:

```
  UPDATE dex_mfgx..insp_master
  SET dex_mfgx..insp_master.costperpart = t2.sct_cst_tot
  FROM dex_mfgx..insp_master AS t1
  INNER JOIN qad_repl..sct_det_sql AS t2
  ON t1.partnum = t2.sct_part
  WHERE t1.partnum = t2.sct_part and t2.sct_cst_date = MAX(t2.sct_cst_date) ;
```

My Error:

```
Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.
```

Not having much luck with HAVING or GROUPING, although I havent used them much..

Any have an idea that would help?

Comment: So, is it mysql or SQL Server?, please use the appropriate tag

Comment: Have you tried getting the MAX with a subquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to solve now. Thanks to Lamak for setting me straight as I was way off base originally.

Something like this I think is what you are looking for.

```
with TotalCosts as
(
    SELECT t2.sct_cst_tot
        , t1.partnum
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by t1.partnun order by t2.sct_cst_date desc)
    FROM dex_mfgx..insp_master AS t1
    INNER JOIN qad_repl..sct_det_sql AS t2 ON t1.partnum = t2.sct_part
)

update t1
set costperpart = tc.sct_cst_tot
from dex_mfgx..insp_master AS t1
join TotalCosts tc on tc.partnum = t1.partnum
where tc.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: the `and t2.sct_cst_date = t2.sct_cst_date` doesn't seem right

Comment: @Lamak I think you are correct. :) I had just copied that from the original and didn't notice it was the same column. Probably just remove it.

Comment: The problem now is that there's more than one row in table 2 per PartNumber, and op just needs the one with the latest date

Comment: @Lamak which is exactly why I put MAX in there. Maybe needs to be grouped by PartNumber? Hard to say as I am guessing.

Comment: Yeah, I meant that op needs the latest date, not the max cost. I assume that the cost can get smaller

Comment: Alright, now you get my upvote (though I don't think that the join is necessary in the CTE, just the `ROW_NUMBER` on `qad_repl..sct_det_sql`)

Comment: @SeanLange Meh.. looks like you got it correct now.  The show is over, but it was entertaining while it lasted ;)

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks guys for the help! This worked perfectly.